# How to solve this limit: $\lim_{x\to \pi}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\cos{\theta}}}$

Tags: limits

How to solve this limit? I thought I could easily solve it using l'hopitals rules, but turns out I can't. Any help would be much appreciated.

$$\lim_{\theta\to \pi}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\sqrt{1+\cos{\theta}}}$$

Comment: If you let $x$ tend to $\pi$, nothing will happen. It will be different if you let $\theta$ tend to $\pi$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp thanks, corrected

Comment: Once you know that the limit exists, you can use l'Hospital: $$x := \lim_{\theta\to\pi}\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}} = \lim_{\theta\to\pi}2\frac{\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}{\sin\theta}\cdot(-\cos\theta) = \frac 2 x.$$Hence, $x^2 = 2$, that is, $x = \sqrt 2$.

Comment: Since $\sin\theta$ changes sign at $\theta=\pi$, it should be fairly clear that either the limit is zero or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Jason is right. So you can actually use Jason's and my comment to show that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I think that would make a good answer.

Comment: Thanks, but they checked your answer already. I will leave it as is.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Aw shucks, but it is a good answer nonetheless :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recall the Pythagorean identity:

$$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)=1$$

Thus,

$$\sin^2(\theta)=1-\cos^2(\theta)=(1+\cos(\theta))(1-\cos(\theta))$$

Or

$$1+\cos(\theta)=\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}$$

And so,

$$\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)}}=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{1-\cos(\theta)}}}=\frac{\sin(\theta)\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}}{|\sin(\theta)|}$$

And as $\theta\to\pi^+$, $\sin(\theta)>0$, thus,

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi^+}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)}}=\lim_{\theta\to\pi^+}\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}=\sqrt2$$

But as $\theta\to\pi^-$, $\sin(\theta)<0$, thus,

$$\lim_{\theta\to\pi^-}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)}}=\lim_{\theta\to\pi^-}-\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}=-\sqrt2$$

So the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you type so fast? Do you have voice commands for LaTeX too :P      +1 for typing

Comment: @JaideepKhare Copy + paste.  How many times do I have to say it?!  Once I have `\sin^2(\theta)`, I copy paste it the entire way, plus I know what I'm doing, which helps.

Comment: So, you had to copy paste it only once. ;)

Comment: Not really.   For example, my last line was a copy of the line above it. And you should not marvel at my speed, but my quality.

Comment: I like your speed... and your quality. ;-)

Comment: Well, it seems that @SimplyBeautifulArt has become rude over time. :-) +1

Comment: Lol, thanks @VidyanshuMishra